# Typo3 resources media files/sys_file_reference for TMENU

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

How can I use resources media files -> Description (Caption) for altTag/altText in menu.

In TYPO3 you have the possibility to use the page properties for a resource image and to set additional metadata. I found this reference: data [sys_file_reference] [6] [description]

```
NO = 1 
NO {
   ATagTitle.field = title
   wrapItemAndSub = |</li>
   allWrap = <li>| 
   after.cObject = IMAGE 
   after.cObject {
      file.import.field = media
      file.import = uploads/media/ 
      file.import.listNum = 0
      file.width = 250c 
      altText = {???:description}
      altText.insertData = 1 
   }
   stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since TYPO3 6.0 the media field uses File Abstraction Layer (FAL) to create references to uploaded objects (e.g. images). Because of this change, you can't use the IMAGE content object to fetch the inserted object, but first have to use the FILES content object.

For you case, the TypoScript should look like this:

```
  after.cObject = FILES 
  after.cObject {
    references.data =  levelmedia:-1, slide
    references.listNum = 0
    renderObj = IMAGE
    renderObj.altText.data = file:current:description
    renderObj.file {
      import.data = file:current:publicUrl
      width = 250c
    }
  }
```

References: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Files/Index.html

Comment: Thanks that was the right tip. Do you have an idea to use listNum when you not working with levelmedia? It will display all pictures when you try:

`after.cObject = FILES
after.cObject {
  references {
    table = pages
    uid.data = field = uid
    fieldName = media
    #listNum = 1 # not working
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    10 = IMAGE
    10 {
      file.import.data = file:current:originalUid
      #file.import.listNum = 1
      file.width = 250 # not working
      altText.data = file:current:title
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @Obeck I would suggest to create a new question for your second question. If my answer solves your original question, then please mark it as accepted.